# How to get all the element tags and content of each tag in HTML file stored in some other folder

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

**Objective is to Get individual text segments from HTML file (not a single stream   string of whole document.)**

I want to scan html files for element tags and text content in between tag pair. I am thinking of doing it something like this :

```
//        var mytags = $('#trans_seg').find('*');
//        var total = mytags.length;
//    
//        for(i = 0; i <= total; i++){
//            console.log(mytags[i].textContent);
//        }
```

**Its done in console mode of firebug !**

I applied this operation in existing HTML file, now how can i do it for other HTML files ?

i have tried somewhat like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    data = '<?php echo mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents('test_html.html')); ?>';
    tags = data.find('*');
    alert($data.length);
});
```

But it is giving error "TypeError: data.find is not a function".

Do ask me question if it still not clear.

**************** Edited *********************************

i got this response when i alert data

```
<!--
```

To change this template, choose Tools | Templates

and open the template in the editor.

-->

```
<head>

    <title></title>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

</head>

<body>

    <div>TODO write content</div>

    <h1>My First Heading</h1>



    <p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
```

Comment: just do alert(data) after getting the content using file_get_content and check whether it is in Object or Html... and please post that content here....

Comment: Is there a reason why you are doing with this jQuery? You can use DOMDocument here http://us3.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php to parse HTML files and do all this using PHP.

Comment: @cryptic can you plz eleborate your answer and explain how can i acheive this, as i can get content via DOMDocument but how can i get individual segment between tag pairs ?

Comment: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php see the examples that they provide on how to access items within a tag pair.

Comment: Thanks crypto, it seems that there is something i must give a try to, I am working on it and will be back if hit with a solution.